# Optimize query for multiple unions

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

We have a table like

```
------------------------------------------
| user_id | timestamp | key      | value |
------------------------------------------
   99     | 1598603308 | Spo2 |      99
   99     | 1598603318 | Spo2 |      98
   99     | 1598603328 | Spo2 |      96
   99     | 1598603338 | Spo2 |      97
...
...
   99     | 1598603307 | Breath |      99
   99     | 1598603311 | Breath |      98
   99     | 1598603315 | Breath |      96
   99     | 1598603319 | Breath |      97
```

The idea is to get the latest Breath & latest Spo2 for the user with id 99.

```
select user_id, timestamp, key, value from session_records
where
user_id = 99 and key = 'Spo2' and value > 0 order by timestamp desc limit 1
**UNION**
select user_id, timestamp, key, value from session_records
where
user_id = 99 and key = 'Breath' and value >= 0 order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

Now the `key` can vary. It can be `HeartRate` or `Sdnn` or something dynamically passed in.

Is there any other way to write this query without unions?

Comment: `UNION ALL` would at least make it a bit faster, but GMB's suggestion is better anyway

Comment: See my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632775/possible-better-sql-query-for-multiple-unions-fetch-latest-5-records-for-diffe/63651848#63651848). That function should work just for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id, key) s.*
from session_record s
where user_id = 99 and key in ('Breath', 'Spo2')
order by user_id, key, timestamp desc
```

You can adapt the `where` clause predicates as you wish - the rest of the query remains the same.