# Possible better SQL Query for multiple UNIONS - fetch latest 5 records for different `key` names

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

We have a table like

```
------------------------------------------
| user_id | timestamp | key      | value |
------------------------------------------
   99     | 1598603308 | Heart | 99
   99     | 1598603318 | Heart | 98
   99     | 1598603328 | Heart | 96
   99     | 1598603338 | Heart | 97
...
...
   99     | 1598603307 | Breath |      12
   99     | 1598603311 | Breath |      21
   99     | 1598603315 | Breath |      13
   99     | 1598603319 | Breath |      15
```

The idea is to get the last 5 Breath & last 5 Heart for the user with id 99.

```
(select user_id, max(t.timestamp), t.key, avg(t.value) from (
    (select user_id, key, timestamp, value from session_records
         where
     user_id = 99 and key = 'HeartRate' and value > 0 order by timestamp desc limit 5)
        union
    (select user_id, key, timestamp, value from session_records
        where
     user_id = 99 and key = 'BreathRate' and value > 0 order by timestamp desc limit 5)
        union
    (select user_id, key, timestamp, value from session_records
        where
     user_id = 99 and key = 'Sdnn' and value > 0 order by timestamp desc limit 5)
)
```

Now the `key` can vary. It can be `HeartRate` or `Sdnn` or something dynamically passed in.

Is there any other way to write this query without unions?

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select user_id, max("timestamp"), "key", avg(value)
from (
  select user_id, "key", "timestamp", value, 
         row_number() over (partition by user_id, "key" order by "timestamp" desc) as rn
  from session_records
  where "key" in ('HeartRate', 'BreathRate', ...)
    and user_id = 99
    and value > 0
) t
where rn <= 5
group by user_id, "key"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select user_id, key, avg(value), max(timestamp)
from (select sr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, key order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from session_records sr
      where user_id = 99 value > 0
     ) sr
where seqnum <= 5
group by user_id, key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you want the ability to specify a variable number of parameters you can create a SQL function which takes an array of values and returns results as a table.

```
create or replace 
function user_latestn( user_id_in  integer
                     , latest_n_in integer 
                     , key_list_in text[]
                     ) 
  returns table(user_id      integer
               , "timestamp" bigint
               , key         text 
               , adv_value   numeric
               )
  language sql 
  strict
as $$
    select user_id,max("timestamp"), key, avg(value)
      from ( select user_id, key, "timestamp", value 
                  , row_number() over (partition by user_id, key 
                                           order by "timestamp" desc) rn
               from session_records
              where key = any (key_list_in)
                and user_id = user_id_in
                and value > 0
           ) t
       where rn <= latest_n_in
       group by user_id, key ;
$$;
```

You can then Select the results. See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d551b70b7e03d0e1513b369441c3d6a0).  

Since you data only included 4 items I reduced the number the number to 3 for the example (ensure at least 1 omitted). Also your data does not match the values in query: Heart does not match HeartRate. I used you data values.